# What is the correspondence between go-logr and uber's zap verbosity levels?

Tags: go, logging, go-zap

I saw that there is log level in Uber Zap implementation:

```
    const (
            // DebugLevel logs are typically voluminous, and are usually disabled in
            // production.
            DebugLevel Level = iota - 1
            // InfoLevel is the default logging priority.
            InfoLevel
            // WarnLevel logs are more important than Info, but don't need individual
            // human review.
            WarnLevel
            // ErrorLevel logs are high-priority. If an application is running smoothly,
            // it shouldn't generate any error-level logs.
            ErrorLevel
            // DPanicLevel logs are particularly important errors. In development the
            // logger panics after writing the message.
            DPanicLevel
            // PanicLevel logs a message, then panics.
            PanicLevel
            // FatalLevel logs a message, then calls os.Exit(1).
            FatalLevel
        )
```

I use this when I set the level in a `sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/log/zap` logger, which uses `go-logr` under the hood:

```
func determineLogLevel(verbosityLevel string) zapcore.Level {
    var zapLevel zapcore.Level
    verbosityLevel = strings.ToLower(verbosityLevel)
    switch verbosityLevel {
    case ERROR:
        zapLevel = zapcore.ErrorLevel
    case WARNING:
        zapLevel = zapcore.WarnLevel
    case INFO:
        zapLevel = zapcore.InfoLevel
    case DEBUG:
        zapLevel = zapcore.DebugLevel
    default:
        zapLevel = zapcore.InfoLevel
    }
    return zapLevel
}

// here zap is "sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/log/zap"
opts := zap.Options{
    StacktraceLevel: ... ,
    Level:           determineLogLevel("ERROR"),
    Encoder:         ... ,
    ZapOpts:         ...,
}
```

But there is also the option of using `logr.Logger.V`.

Is the level value here the same as in Uber Zap's constants? ( `DebugLevel`, `InfoLevel`, `WarnLevel`, ....)

I also saw this:

> flag --zap-log-level: Zap Level to configure the verbosity of logging. Can be one of ‘debug’, ‘info’, ‘error’, or any integer value > 0 which corresponds to custom debug levels of increasing verbosity”

Is this flag value the same as `zapcore.Level` in the `sigs.k8s.io`'s `zap.Options`?

The documentation for [`logr.Logger.V`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-logr/logr#Logger.V)

```
    // V returns an Logger value for a specific verbosity level, relative to
    // this Logger.  In other words, V values are additive.  V higher verbosity
    // level means a log message is less important.  It's illegal to pass a log
    // level less than zero.
    V(level int) Logger
```

Comment: Are you asking if there's a correspondence between the `int` passed to `V` and uber's zap own levels?

Comment: @blackgreen - yes and also about the different between V ,level and zap-log-level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correspondence between `go-logr` and `go.uber.org/zap` log levels is given by:

```
zapLevel = -1 * logrLevel
```

In other words, the `go-logr` level is the **inverse** of `zap` level. This information is available in [`go-logr/zapr`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-logr/zapr) package docs:

> Levels in logr correspond to custom debug levels in Zap. Any given level in logr is represents by its inverse in zap (`zapLevel = -1*logrLevel`). For example V(2) is equivalent to log level -2 in Zap, while V(1) is equivalent to Zap's DebugLevel.

You can also see a concrete example of how the level is initialized by looking at the implementation of `logr.Logger.V` by `zapr` package:

```
func (zl *zapLogger) V(level int) logr.Logger {
    return &zapLogger{
        lvl: zl.lvl - zapcore.Level(level),
        l:   zl.l,
    }
}
```

The method `zapr.NewLogger` constructs a `zapr.zapLogger` with `lvl` field set to `zap.InfoLevel` (which you know is `0`), so each time you call `V` on this implementation, it subtracts the given int value, thus obtaining its negative.

---

The flag `--zap-log-level` is mapped from the string value passed on the command line (or k8s yaml config) to the Uber Zap's level as-is, based on this:

```
var levelStrings = map[string]zapcore.Level{
    "debug": zap.DebugLevel,
    "info":  zap.InfoLevel,
    "error": zap.ErrorLevel,
}
```

The numerical value is then multiplied by `-1` and then set to the `logr.Logger` implementation, as required by the documentation quoted above.

Comment: and the zap-log-level flag is for the V calculation ?

Comment: How I can control what will be print and what is not ? where i can control on V levek testLog.V(0).Info("This is a test0")
  testLog.V(1).Info("This is a test1")
  testLog.V(2).Info("This is a test2")
  testLog.V(3).Info("This is a test3")
  testLog.V(-1).Info("This is a test-1")
  testLog.V(-2).Info("This is a test-2")

Comment: @user1365697 I updated the answer. the flag is just another way to set the log level to the k8s `logr` logger.

Comment: @@user1365697 - If i set the logger to info LEVEL how I can get the messages with V(1),V(2),V(3) .....

Comment: @user1365697 If the Uber zap logger is set to `InfoLevel` you use `V` with negative values to print warn, error, dpanic, etc. E.g. `logger.V(0).Info("foo")` prints `foo` at `info`, `logger.V(-1).Info("foo")` prints `foo` at `warn`, because `-1` is multiplied by `-1` = `1`, which in zap is `WarnLevel`

Comment: @user1365697 and therefore zap logger initialized with `DebugLevel` will print `V(1).Info` at `debug` level, because `1` becomes `-1`